# Play Framework Hanging when hitting app in browser

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, freeze

I am running an app in Play using `activator run`, and maybe 3 out of 5 times, it will just hang, when I go to `http://localhost:9000/`, it just sits there spinning forever.

I'm seeing a lot of `promise timed out` errors also.

Where should I look for this issue?

I turned up logging with `logLevel := Level.Debug`, but I see nothing amiss.  While the app is spinning, I see no logging at all.

---

If I just let it sit and spin for a long time (~5 min) it will eventually give this error:

```
[info] play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PrivilegedActionException: null]]
[info]  at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:265) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
[info]  at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
[info]  at play.core.server.Server$class.logExceptionAndGetResult$1(Server.scala:50) [play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
[info]  at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:59) [play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
[info]  at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:57) [play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
[info]  at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522) [scala-library.jar:na]
[info]  at play.core.server.Server$class.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:57) [play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
[info]  at play.core.server.NettyServer.getHandlerFor(NettyServer.scala:33) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
[info]  at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$8.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
[info]  at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$8.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
[info] Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: null
[info]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader$.play$runsupport$Reloader$$withReloaderContextClassLoader(Reloader.scala:39) ~[na:na]
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader.reload(Reloader.scala:321) ~[na:na]
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:113) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1423) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:902) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
[info] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300000 milliseconds]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
[info]  at play.forkrun.ForkRun$$anonfun$askForReload$1.apply(ForkRun.scala:127) ~[na:na]
[info]  at play.forkrun.ForkRun$$anonfun$askForReload$1.apply(ForkRun.scala:125) ~[na:na]
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anonfun$reload$1.apply(Reloader.scala:323) ~[na:na]
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anon$3.run(Reloader.scala:43) ~[na:na]
[info]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
```

---

I should mention that this is a *very* simple app.  It is doing nothing but rendering some HTML so far.

---

Its too bad, because it seems like there is a lot of good in the framework, but it is just *slow* and terribly unreliable.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560348/how-to-change-future-timeout-with-play-framework-2-1-0 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747778/why-do-i-get-a-very-long-timeout-in-my-playframework-app. Looks like a known issue with some Play configurations.

Comment: @Gaël - Giving the forked run setting a shot - thanks

Comment: @Gaël Commenting out this line: `//fork in run := true` made the difference.  Night and day.

Comment: @mtyson +1 for the feedback on play framework "slow and terribly unreliable". I couldn't agree more. Frameworks that are supposed to make work easier shouldn't be so annoyingly difficult to setup and work with. By the way, commenting out the line: `//fork in run := true` did help as suggested. Another +1 for that :D

Answer (score 2):

`fork in run := true` is added always when starting the app from Activators UI (for spawning processes) so stop using UI for given app (maybe add startup config in your IDE) or always remember to clear/comment/set to false.

Comment: Just FYI - This app wasn't created via the UI