# Play 2.5 application requests hang

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5

I'm running a small scala Play application in dev mode on a vagrant box using activator run. When accessing the app from the browser some of the requests hang for what looks like indefinitely.

This seems to be the same issue as described in this question for play 2.0 [Play Framework Hanging when hitting app in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445666/play-framework-hanging-when-hitting-app-in-browser). The solution suggested there however doesn't seem to apply to the latest version of play.

I'm not sure where to start investigating this issue. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So after investigating it for a bit we realised that requests hang on routes that were protected by deadbolt. After replacing deadbolt all went back to normal. We were using deadbolt-scala 2.5.0 if anyone has any idea what might have been the issue there a comment here would be welcomed. But for now we stopped using the library.